# Need to find the rectangles title when dragging my marker to it google map api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map with 5 markers and 25 rectangles. Then I drag the marker to a rectangle I want to know the title of the rectangle.

Right now I have a listener to the rectangles, just for seeing that they is named correctly and this works fine

```
google.maps.event.addListener(partialRectangle, 'click', function() {
  console.log(this.title);
});
```

and I also have a listner to the markers to get some information then dragging them and that´s works fine too

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    console.log(marker.getPosition());
    console.log(this.title);

});
```

Any idea how to get out the info about in which rectangle I dropped the markers?

This code solved my problems

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++){ // looping through rectangles
    if(partialRectangles[i].bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()))
        console.log(partialRectangles[i].title);
} 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each marker's `dragend` listener, loop through all the rectangle's `LatLngBounds` and use the `contains(latLng:LatLng)` function to determine if the new marker's position is inside that rectangle's `LatLngBounds`.

Pseudo-code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {

         if(rectangles[i].getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
               console.log(rectangles[i].title);
         }
    }

});
```